# Widget translation on my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, translation

I am adding i18n to the widget on [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/). I've correctly created the pot file, and po and mo files for Spanish and English. All of the Strings are being displayed with `_e()` on the form file.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/
include/
    ListCategoryPostsWidget.php
    lcp_widget_form.php
languages/
    es_ES.mo
    en_US.mo
plugin.php
```

There are other files, but these are the ones involved in translation. From my Widget class (ListCategoryPostsWidget.php) I'm using this to register the translation:

```
$translation_dir = '../languages';
load_plugin_textdomain( 'list-category-posts', null, $translation_dir );
```

And this is the code I'm using to include the form file in ListCategoryPostsWidget.php file:

```
/** @see WP_Widget::form */
function form($instance) {
    include('lcp_widget_form.php');
}
```

Default language is English, so that works fine. But when I set WP_LANG to "es_ES" on my wp-config, I still see the text on the widget in English. Any ideas?
**EDIT:** So, I'm adding some more code:

```
<p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
<?php _e("Title", 'list-category-posts')?></label>
```

This is how I'm using the _e function in lcp_widget_form.php.

Comment: Can we see the *output* code, to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Sure, which code? The html generated by the widget? That one just shows the Strings in the _e function for eg: _e("Category") displays "Category".

Comment: Yes: the *PHP code* that *generates the HTML output* - specifically, the *strings* that get output. **HINT: If you're using `_e( "Category" )`, you're doing it wrong, and that's why it's not working.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> The html generated by the widget? That one just shows the Strings in the _e function for eg: _e("Category") displays "Category"

I suspect that you've not configured your translation strings properly. You need to include the **textdomain** in every translation string function call, or else the strings will *never get translated*.

e.g. for your textdomain `'list-category-posts'`:

```
_e( 'Category' )
```

...should instead be:

```
_e( 'Category', 'list-category-posts' )
```

Ensure that all of your translation string functions are declared accordingly.

Comment: Ooops, sorry I was wrong on the comments, I am using it the way I'm supposed to: _e("Category", 'list-category-posts')

Comment: That's why we need to see the actual code... :)

Comment: I added some more details on the question.

Comment: This is an old question but was just checking my account over here. i18n was finally added: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/changelog/, thanks Chip! :)